# Chrome prefers web font over local font

Tags: google-chrome, google-font-api, google-fonts

I am not understanding something about the way Chrome loads google fonts. Here is my html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Montserrat Regular Google Fonts</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <p style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-size: 30px;">
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt..."
    </p>        
</body>
```

I have Montserrat Regular installed on my Windows 10 machine. 
According to this: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat, locally installed fonts have priority.

But when I check Dev Tools, Chrome reports under "Rendered Fonts" - Montserrat (Network resource -93 Glyphs)

I tested this on Firefox (reports "Montserrat Regular - System"), and Edge(reports "Montserrat Regular used Montserrat (Local, System,95 chars).

Why is Chrome preferring the network resource over the locally installed font?

Comment: My Windows 10 machine has Ubuntu font installed. I tested your code for Ubuntu font on all browsers and it is not just Chrome all browsers downloaded Google font.

Comment: @TejasSarade, actually only Chrome seems to be downloading the font. Edge and Firefox only download the Google Fonts CSS file, as they should, but not the actual Google font.

Comment: If I go to fonts tab in Firefox developer console, I see Ubuntu as web font only. Same for IE/Edge. I don't see any local font used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be related to [this opened chromium issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=627143).

> Linking "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Special+Elite"
>
> Returns this CSS:
>
> ```
> /* latin */
> @font-face {
>   font-family: 'Special Elite';
>   font-style: normal;
>   font-weight: 400;
>   src: local('Special Elite Regular'), local('SpecialElite-Regular'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/specialelite/v8/9-wW4zu3WNoD5Fjka35JmzxObtw73-qQgbr7Be51v5c.woff2) format('woff2');
>   unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2212, U+2215;
> }
> ```
>
> The src correctly references the font face name. Chrome does not find
>   the locally installed font and falls back to using the web font.
>   Firefox does find the locally installed font.
>
> If you modify the CSS to reference local('Special Elite') (i.e. the
>   font family name), then the behaviour is reversed: Chrome finds the
>   local font and Firefox does not.