# Why does browsers render only some locally installed font but not all?

Tags: css, browser, webfonts, web-safe-fonts

Was testing a locally installed font for my websites header `font-family: 'Vladimir Script'`. However chrome did not render the text in `Vladimir Script`. When, I specified `Calibri` (also locally installed) as the text's `font-family` then chrome did style the text in `Calibri`.

Why browser did not render the text when `font-family: 'Vladimir Script'` was specified but did style in `Calibri`?

Is it due to chrome considering `Calibri` as web safe and using the locally installed `.ttf` file to style the text when not delivered over web/network (using `@font-face`). If yes, does each browser have their own set of fonts that are considered `web-safe`.

Thanks

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51021201/chrome-prefers-web-font-over-local-font

Comment: The bug reports that chrome does not find the locally installed font but firefox does, but then why chrome uses Calibri, also locally installed?